# How do I get nested divs to be same height and expand to the largest of the heights?

Tags: html, css

This is best explained with a JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/4beugz4w/1/ and code examples.

I am trying to design a very standard header with a name/logo thing on the left and navigation on the right.  I can't get the heights of the divs to be right and also to vertically center the navigation links according to the middle of how the name/logo thing is.  I hope that made sense.

HTML

```
  <div id="inside1">
    Name or Logo
  </div>

  <div id="inside2">
     <ul>
       <li>About Me</li>
       <li>Work</li>
       <li>Resume</li>
     </ul>
  </div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
#outside
{
  background-color: red;
}

#outside > *
{
  display: inline;
}

#inside1
{
  background-color: blue;
  font-size: 30px;
}

#inside2
{
  background-color: green;
  float: right;
}

#inside2 ul li
{
    font-size: 16px;
    display: inline;
    margin-left: 30px;
}
```

Comment: You want something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/vx79jr20/) ?

Comment: I think you should also consider using a framework like bootstrap for future reference, you wont run into this issues and you will have responsive build it, from there its all you editing and styling to your hearts desire

Comment: I hope [this](https://jsfiddle.net/alireza_safian/4beugz4w/13/) can help you.

Comment: is this are you trying to achieve? https://jsfiddle.net/blasteralfred/4beugz4w/14/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### UPDATE 31-03-2017

Since this answer was posted in Dec, 2015 things have changed for the (even) better css Grid layout module. This module has recently been implemented in all browsers with the exception of partial support in the latest version of Edge (http://caniuse.com/#search=grid).

A quote by Chris Coyier from CSS tricks explaining the difference between flexbox and grid:

> CSS Grid Layout is the most powerful layout system available in CSS. It is a 2-dimensional system, meaning it can handle both columns and rows, unlike flexbox which is largely a 1-dimensional system. You work with Grid Layout by applying CSS rules both to a parent element (which becomes the Grid Container) and to that elements children (which become Grid Items).

If you would like to check it out, there is a CSS Grid guide on CSS-Tricks which is just as clear as the flexbox guide link that already exists in this answer. [Go check it out here!](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)

If you require support for somewhat older browsers, e.g. IE 10+, flexbox can be made to work with that but grid isn't supported there. (http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox)

### ORIGINAL ANSWER

In [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4beugz4w/8/) I have the desired result you want.
I'm using [`display: flex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes) here together with more of it's properties to make things work.

The *flexbox* model is a very modern one which pretty much solves *(almost if not)* all positioning problems by giving you the things that you need as a dev, common tasks are made easier with `flexbox` and browser vendors implemented it fast so that we can basically use it today as the older browsers like *Internet Explorer < 11* are no longer a bother like *Internet Explorer <= 8* used to be.

If you're not familiar with using `flexbox` I would definitely recommend you read up on it since it will make your life a breeze where with conventional methods (`inline-block`, `float`) it would be horror.

The following things I removed within your code:

- removed the entire `#outside > * {}` selector as it was useless
  to elaborate: `display: inline` prevents elements from receiving any `height` or `margin-top` / `margin-bottom` in any way due to it literally becoming a text element.
- removed `float: right` from `#inside2` since it wasn't required anymore
  when using `display: flex` **all** children are *flex-children* that gain special properties to align themselves using the `flexbox` model

The following things I added within your code:

- `display: flex` to `#outside`
  this property allows it's children to be sized according to the [`flexbox`](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) model
- `flex-flow: row wrap` to `#outside`
  this allows multiple children to be aligned on the same line
- `justify-content: space-between` to `#outside`
  makes sure that your items are taking the full width of the screen but with whitespace in between to fill the gap
- `flex: 0 0 auto` to both `#inside1` and `#inside2`
  prevents elements from growing bigger than they need to be.

For useful reads on how `flexbox` works / how well it's supported,

1. [CSS-tricks guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)
2. [MDN on flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes)
3. [Browser support for flexbox](http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox)

Comment: Thank you!  This answer was informative, pointed me to the new flexbox model, and ultimately helped me solve my issue.

Answer (score 1):

CSS:

```
#outside
{
  background-color: red;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

#outside > *
{
  display: table-cell;
}

#inside1
{
  background-color: blue;
  font-size: 30px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#inside2
{
  background-color: green;
  float: right;

}

#inside2 ul li
{
    font-size: 16px;
    display: inline;
    margin-left: 30px;
}
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4beugz4w/12/)

Answer (score 1):

Here you go !!

**NOTE**
Apply `display: table` for the parent and `display: table-cell` for the child. Use `vertical-align: middle` to the child div to make it align vertical center.

```css
body {} #outside {
  background-color: red;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
#outside > * {
  display: inline;
}
#inside1 {
  background-color: blue;
  font-size: 30px;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
#inside2 {
  background-color: green;
  float: right;
}
#inside2 ul li {
  font-size: 16px;
  display: inline;
  margin-left: 30px;
}
ul {
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div id="outside">

  <div id="inside1">
    Name or Logo
  </div>

  <div id="inside2">
    <ul>
      <li>About Me</li>
      <li>Work</li>
      <li>Resume</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

**Use below css and change as per your requirement**
I am using display table/table-cell for cross-browser, though you can get the same result through css flex-box.

```
#outside
{
  background-color: red;
  display:table;
  width:100%;
}

#outside > *
{
  display: table-cell;
}

#inside1
{
  background-color: blue;
  font-size: 30px;
  width:30%;
}

#inside2
{
  background-color: green;
  text-align: right;
  width:70%;
}

#inside2 ul li
{
    font-size: 16px;
    display: inline;
    margin-left: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use on a wrapper

```
display: table
```

and

```
display: table-cell; 
vertical-alignment: top
```

on its inner elements.

[Working example.](https://jsfiddle.net/huggb8m4/)